# HTTPS for JBoss 5

Tags: java, ssl, https, jboss

Hy guys,

I am trying to setting up HTTPS for JBOSS 5, basically these are my steps:

**1)** using keytool I added certificate I need into the file cacerts **C:...\jre\lib\security\cacerts** and named with alias 'example'.

**2)** I verified that the certificate was correctly added, this is a excerpt of the .txt file generated from the new cacerts file:

```
....
Nome alias: example
Data di creazione: 22-ott-2014
Tipo entry: trustedCertEntry

Proprietario: ST=Italy, L=Padova, EMAILADDRESS=dite.sistemi.middleware@infocamere.it, CN=*.intra.infocamere.it, OU=FTEC, O=InfoCamere S.C.p.A./02313821007, C=IT
Autorità emittente: CN=InfoCert Certification Authority TEST, OU=Internet Services, O=InfoCert SpA, C=IT
Numero di serie: 75d1
Valido da: Thu Sep 12 11:24:21 CEST 2013 a: Sat Jan 11 15:13:30 CET 2014
Impronte digitali certificato:
     MD5:  68:C3:BE:D7:DB:2E:B6:08:B6:09:84:8F:7B:EE:26:43
     SHA1: 36:CB:C3:98:36:CA:13:DF:DE:15:BA:42:9D:65:7D:B2:A5:BC:1C:A0
     Nome algoritmo firma: SHA1withRSA
     Versione: 3
...
```

**3)** I copy the file cacerts into JBOSS directory **D:\EnterprisePlatform-5.1.2\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\all\conf\cacerts**

**4)** I uncomment file **D:\EnterprisePlatform-5.1.2\jboss-eap-5.1\jboss-as\server\all\deploy\jbossweb.sar\server.xml**, like the following:

```
<Connector protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" 
           port="8443" address="${jboss.bind.address}"
           scheme="https" secure="true" clientAuth="false" 
           keystoreFile="${jboss.server.home.dir}/conf/cacerts" keyAlias="example" 
           keystorePass="changeit" sslProtocol = "TLS" />
```

**5)** I start JBOSS and I get following error:

```
DEPLOYMENTS MISSING DEPENDENCIES:
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/admin-console" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/invoker" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jbossws" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/jmx-console" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/juddi" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")
  Deployment "jboss.web.deployment:war=/web-console" is missing the following dependencies:
    Dependency "jboss.web:service=WebServer" (should be in state "Create", but is actually in state "** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **")

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s): LifecycleException:  Protocol handler initialization failed: java.io.IOException: Alias name example does not identify a key entry
  Deployment "jboss.web:service=WebServer" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.web:service=WebServer' **
```

I don't understand why, because the JBOSS cacerts path is correct (verified that). And inside this file there is also an alias called 'example'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the private key and certificate in the keystore. According the question, you only have the certificated with alias `example`.

With your private key and public certificate, you need to create a **PKCS12** keystore first, then convert it into a **JKS**.

**Create PKCS12 keystore from private key and public certificate.**

```
 openssl pkcs12 -export -name example -in server.crt -inkey server.key \
            -out server.p12
```

**Create PKCS12 keystore from private key and public certificate including CA certificate.**

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in server.crt -inkey server.key \
           -out server.p12 -name example \
           -CAfile ca.crt -caname root
```

**Convert the pkcs12 file to a java keystore**

```
keytool -importkeystore \
    -deststorepass changeit -destkeypass changeit -destkeystore server.jks\
    -srckeystore server.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass some-password \
    -alias example
```

To verify the contents of the JKS, you can use this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore server.jks
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Federico Sierra, so if I understand well, I need first to create my keystore and add into my own certificate, then I need to include in the keystore the CA certificate , is it correct?

Comment: @Giorgio yes, you must create the keystore with the certificate and private key, if you ned add CA certifcate you can do. http://docs.jboss.org/jbossweb/3.0.x/ssl-howto.html